# Create a Composite that adapt to my data in Eclipse SWT

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, swt, composite

My First try is:

```
public MultiLangugeText(Composite parent, int style) {
    super(parent, style);
    setLayout(new RowLayout(SWT.HORIZONTAL));

    Map<Locale, String> texts = new HashMap<Locale, String>();
    texts.put(Locale.GERMAN, "Hey du");
    texts.put(Locale.ENGLISH, "Hey you");
    texts.put(Locale.FRENCH, "Bon Jour");
    setTexts(texts);

public void setTexts(Map<Locale, String> texts) {
    for (Locale locale : texts.keySet()) {
        createTextComposite(locale, texts.get(locale));
    }
}

private void createTextComposite(Locale locle, String localizedString) {
    Composite composite = formToolkit.createComposite(this, SWT.BORDER);
    formToolkit.paintBordersFor(composite);
    composite.setLayout(new RowLayout(SWT.HORIZONTAL));

    CLabel label = new CLabel(composite, SWT.NONE);
    label.setText(locle.toString());
    formToolkit.adapt(label);
    formToolkit.paintBordersFor(label);

    Text txtString = new Text(composite, SWT.BORDER);
    txtString.setText(localizedString);
    formToolkit.adapt(txtString, true, true);
}
```

But this code will not draw anything on my UI. At least when I try to render it in the Deisigner and in the Preview. I have to tests if this works, when I use it in my application. But I don't get where error is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay it only fails in the designer, not when you actually use the composite elsewehre.

Comment: One additional reason not to use these designers ;)

Comment: Maybe, but the Disgner also gave me a lot of code examples. Would be hard to find everything the designer teached me by myself. So in the end: A combination of code and Deigner is the best. One have to learn what the designer does and breaks ;)